# Function for finding multiple values from an array and replace data in a specific column based on the matching IDs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets, google-apps-script, foreach

I have an Event Scheduler spreadsheet where I need to add or remove employee's from column A in the query table, for each row I have a dropdown list to select names.I use a script that can find only one name at a time on the database sheet and replace it after clicking a buttom. The search engine is based on IDs (column A). I need this function to be able to get multiple names and replace them all at once instead. Can anyone help me please? This is the code I have for only one value.

```
function saveRecord7() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const formWS = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard')
  const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName('Static_VDatabase_UID')
  const idCell = formWS.getRange('G7')
  const fieldRange =["AB7"]
  const clearcell = formWS.getRange('AB7')

  const id = idCell.getValue()
  if(id== ''){

    //createNewRecord()
    return
  }
  
   const cellFound = dataWS.getRange("A:A")
                  .createTextFinder(id)
                  .matchCase(true)
                  .matchEntireCell(true)
                  .findNext()

    if(!cellFound) return  
    const row = cellFound.getRow()            
  
   const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => formWS.getRange(f).getValue())
   fieldValues.unshift()
   dataWS.getRange(row,20,1,fieldValues.length).setValues([fieldValues])  

 clearcell.clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function saveRecordsBatch() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const formWS = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName('Static_VDatabase_UID');

  // Assuming IDs start from G1 and values from AB1
  const idsRange = formWS.getRange('G1:G'); // Adjust the range as needed
  const valuesRange = formWS.getRange('AB1:AB'); // Adjust the range as needed

  const ids = idsRange.getValues().filter(String); // Remove empty rows
  const values = valuesRange.getValues().filter(String); // Remove empty rows

  if (ids.length !== values.length) {
    // Make sure each ID has a corresponding value
    throw new Error('Mismatch between IDs and values length');
  }

  ids.forEach((idArray, index) => {
    const id = idArray[0];
    if (id === '') {
      return; // Skip empty IDs
    }

    const cellFound = dataWS.getRange("A:A")
      .createTextFinder(id)
      .matchCase(true)
      .matchEntireCell(true)
      .findNext();

    if (!cellFound) return;
    const row = cellFound.getRow();

    // Assuming you want to replace the value in column 20
    dataWS.getRange(row, 20).setValue(values[index][0]);
  });

  // Clear the input ranges after processing
  idsRange.clearContent();
  valuesRange.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.